# Amazon S3 storing images through Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

Can anyone tell why this code will not put images in either my mysql database or my amazon S3 database.  I'm basically trying to save a file and recall it and I don't even get storage.  Here is my controller code:

```
if ($request->file('board_img')) {
    $hashname=$request->file('board_img')->hashName();

    Storage::disk('s3')->put('wod-pictures/', $request->file('board_img'), 'public');

    $wod_img="wod-pictures/" . $hashname;
  }else{
    $wod_img=$request->get('wod_img');
  }

//creating the new WOD and saving it into the database from the
//user entered values
$daily_wod = new Wod(['user_id'=>$user_id, 'strength'=>$strength,
                      'strength_notes'=>$strength_notes,'wod_type'=>$wod_type,
                      'wod'=>$wod, 'wod_results'=>$wod_results, 'wod_notes'=>$wod_notes,
                      'wod_img'=>$wod_img]);
$daily_wod->save();
```

And here is the part of the form:

```
<form action="/wod" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  {{ csrf_field() }}

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="board_img" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Picture of your WOD (whiteboard)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input
             type="file"
             name="board_img">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any ideas?  I have similar code where it stores a profile image and that works perfectly.  For some reason it will not store this one though.

Comment: So now with that code it does save it into my amazon S3 bucket but it will not save in into my mysql database

Comment: Brad have you checked the fillable fields?

Comment: YOU'RE MY HERO!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Haha, sometimes we overlook the most simple causes including myself then we laugh at our selves when we realize because we think its something much more difficult.. Its what makes a developer!